# How to format Status Check Responses in Azure Devops Pull Requests

Tags: azure-devops

I have a branch policy that enforces the use of pull requests into a specific branch.
The policy also requires that an external status check is passed, in this case a web hook is triggered by the creation or update of the pull request.  The web hook calls a web api which updates the status of the pull request via the devops REST API to set the required state check to `succeeded` or `failed` and include a description.

The description posted to the devops REST API is then displayed in the pull request in the event of a filed status check.  For example:

[image: display of failed status check in pull request]

I have control of the content of the returned description from the web api endpoint, and I am looking for a way to control the formatting of the displayed message in the pull request.  Specifically a way to break the text over multiple lines.

I have tried adding a `<br/>` (shown above) or `\n` or `\r` or even `\r\n` to the text, all with no success.

Is it possible to do this? is there any parsing of the returned text, maybe to allow the use of something like markdown?